# Как вывести итоговую сумму букв?

Tags: python

````
y = input('Введите строку:\n')

for i in x:
    count = 0
    for r in y:
        if i == r:
            count += 1
    if count > 0:
       print('Букв', i, 'было', count)
            
print('Всего букв: ')```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что такое сумма букв?

Comment: я так понял их кол-во

Answer (score 0):

Если вам просто нужно подсчитать количество букв в предложении, то вот вариант:

```
import string
line = input('Введите строку: ')

for p in string.punctuation:
    if p in line:
        line = line.replace(p, '')
line = line.replace(' ', '')
count = 0

for word in line:
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно короче подсчитать кол-во букв в фразе:

```
print(len(input('Введите строку: ').replace(" ", "")))
```

Ну или сформировать список неучитываемых символов:

```
data_replace = [' ', '.', ',', '-']
text_data = input('Введите строку: ')
for i in data_replace:
    text_data = text_data.replace(i, "")
print(len(text_data))
```

Или по другому пути - тут быстрее подсчет будет:

```
data_replace = "!\"#$%&'()*+, -./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"
text_data = input('Введите строку: ')
count = 0
for i in text_data:
    if i in data_replace:
        continue
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Нужно ещё учесть, что там могут быть другие знаки, помимо пробелов.

Comment: @arnold, добавил дополнение